# Why Larecipe can't load correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Larecipe in the project and he can't load correctly. When i see "/docs/1.0/overview", get errors in console and layout can't be load.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CreateLarecipe is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: LaRecipe is not defined

I made package updates and unfortunately it did not help.

```
Laravel Framework 5.7.28
"binarytorch/larecipe": "^2.1",
```

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan larecipe:install`?

Comment: Yes i did it after install package.

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yes i tried, nothing happend.

Comment: What laravel version have you installed larecipe to?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.7.28

Comment: `php artisan package:discover` ?

Comment: Still nothing, the same error.

Comment: Wait it is a javascript error! `npm run development`?

Comment: Yes, is that javascript error in larecipe /docs. This command didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the LaRecipe service provider not being registered (or auto-registered).

Add the service provider to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers

    BinaryTorch\LaRecipe\LaRecipeServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: Nothing happend, still error. All resources are loaded, the problem is only in this javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing.

Try running both these Artisan commands:

```bsh
php artisan larecipe:install
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=larecipe_assets --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I think you have to recreate boostrap/cache/compiled.php file.

```
php artisan optimize
```